# Index scan results in a lot of physical reads (Oracle)

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle11g, pagination, query-performance

There have two tables with more than **20 million** records. The database version is Oracle **11.2.0.3.13 Standard Edition**

```
SQL> select count(*) from atsd_tra_trade_print;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  20000000

SQL> select count(*) from atsd_mob_allocation_pos;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  20551780
```

We run the following queries on the tables. **Query structures are similar**. Query is intended for pagination. **The sort column on both the queries are indexed** and dont contain any NULL values. The queries and the corresponding autotrace output / plan is given below.

Index **INDX_ATTP_6** is created on ATSD_TRA_TRADE_PRINT(**TRANSACT_TIME**)

Index **INDX_AMAP_6** is created on ATSD_MOB_SETTLEMENT_POS(**DATE_TIME**)

Cardinality of the indexes are as follows

INDX_ATTP_6 - 5972

INDX_AMAP_6 - 5974

Both columns above are of datatype **varchar2**.

Both queries were run **after flushing the buffer_cache**. Schema statistics was also gathered.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT T2.*, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (
SELECT *
FROM ATSDN_TRA_TRADE_PRINT T
WHERE LATEST = 1
ORDER BY TRANSACT_TIME) T2)
WHERE RN > 0 and ROWNUM <= 28;
```

Output:

```
28 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.16

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3823692003

-------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost     (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |              |    28 | 60060 |     8       (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |              |       |       |        |              |
|*  2 |   VIEW              |              |    28 | 60060 |     8   (0)|     00:00:01 |
|   3 |    COUNT            |              |       |       |        |             |
|   4 |     VIEW            |              |    28 | 59696 |     8   (0)|     00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ATSD_TRA_TRADE_PRINT |  7488K|      3234M|     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       INDEX FULL SCAN       | INDX_ATTP_6          |    57 |           |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
 ---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=28)
   2 - filter("RN">0)
   5 - filter("LATEST"=1)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
    571  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
    948  consistent gets
     49  physical reads
      0  redo size
  18586  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    535  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
     29  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
     28  rows processed
```

**The above query executes quickly as expected. But the query on the other table results in a long execution time. The only observation I could see was there is a large amount of physical reads.** Both query execution plans look similar too.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT T2.*, ROWNUM as RN FROM ( 
SELECT *
FROM ATSD_MOB_ALLOCATION_POS AL
WHERE  LATEST = 1
ORDER BY DATE_TIME) T2)
WHERE RN > 0 and ROWNUM <= 28;
```

Output:

```
28 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:01:52.28

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 884170602

-------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost     (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |             |    28 | 38892 | 7   (0)|     00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |             |   |   |        |      |
|*  2 |   VIEW              |             |    28 | 38892 | 7   (0)|     00:00:01 |
|   3 |    COUNT            |             |   |   |        |      |
|   4 |     VIEW            |             |    28 | 38528 | 7   (0)|     00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ATSD_MOB_ALLOCATION_POS |        14M|  5863M| 7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       INDEX FULL SCAN       | INDX_AMAP_6         |    39 |   | 4       (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=28)
   2 - filter("RN">0)
   5 - filter("LATEST"=1)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
    281  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
 335395  consistent gets
 332763  physical reads
    116  redo size
  13582  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    535  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
     17  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
     28  rows processed
```

Can someone please enlighten me why this is happening. Thanks in advance ...  :)

Comment: How many rows in total do you have that satisfy the criteria (without the rownum)?

Comment: 10 million for the first query and 15 million for the second query

Comment: @AhamedFazlulWahab Please format the posted explain plan.

Comment: @AhamedFazlulWahab The estimated time in the explain plan is just a second, however, as you say it executes much longer than a second. I think the `statistics` are not gathered up to date.

Comment: Do you have a license for real-time SQL monitoring? Did you try to execute the query with gather_stats_hint?

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B - Statistics were gathered. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the index structure ... when it traverses through the index INDX_AMAP_6 in asc fashion it has to read through 5 million records before it comes across rows which satisfies the filter criteria "LATEST =1". A composite index on the sorting column and the filer column resolved the issue.

create index AMAP_TEST1 on atsd_mob_allocation_pos (latest, date_time);